# Uasort with namespace does not work

Tags: php, namespaces

Unfortunately I am having problems using `uasort` (or any function which expects a callback function) within a Namespace.

Within this script I am not using any classes (therefore no OOP).

I didn't come up with any solution (declaring the Namespace with the callback function did not help).

I am always getting the error (or rather notice): `PHP Warning: uasort() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback,[...]`

That is my (simplified) code:

```
<?php namespace Wire;
include("../index.php");

$test[0] = "Test1";
$test[1] = "Test2";
$test[2] = "Test3";

function selfsort($a,$b){
  $stats["Test1"] = 5;
  $stats["Test2"] = 6;
  $stats["Test3"] = 0;
  if ($stats[$a]==$stats[$b]) return 0;
  return ($stats[$a]<$stats[$b])?-1:1;
}

function getPrio($arr){
  uasort($arr, 'selfsort');
  //usort($arr, array(__NAMESPACE__, 'selfsort')); //doesn't work either: 
  return $arr;
}

//returns PHP Warning: uasort() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback, function 'selfsort' not found or invalid function name in...
print_r(getPrio($test));
```

Is there any possible way to declare that I want to use `uasort` with that specific function or any other workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was a rather stupid question, but for anyone coming up with this problem and searching for hours, I found the answer from the PHP manual comments section for callables.

There it says:

> When trying to make a callable from a function name located in a namespace, you MUST give the fully qualified function name (regardless of the current namespace or use statements).

[Link to PHP manual comment section](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.callable.php#119166)

For my particular question, the answer would have been:

```
uasort($arr, 'Wire\selfsort');
```

Comment: @LawrenceCherone That would work, but as I need the same function to be called from a different function I did not want to repeat myself. But thank you for this!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are using the namespace for here, but try:

`uasort($arr, '\Wire\selfsort');`

Comment: There is some code missing, where the namespace is being used. But your answer is right, even though I found the answer from the PHP manual comments section in the meantime. Thank you!